# Firefox Performance Tab : Minor GC problem

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, firefox

As a way to investigate the not ideal performance of our website i start reading 
about
 the performance tab in FIREFOX.

For example here (https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/07/18/clawing-our-way-back-to-precision/)

After a performance recording i can see that a lot of DOM events like the one in the picture are almost lasting for 2,3 seconds and underneath they have a great amount of Minor GC.Or some promise callbacks that last for 5 seconds and underneath they have Dom events which they have Minor GC as their children.

I can see that this is may be the cause of the bad performance.But i cant actually understand neither what is the cause of that or what it means in practical terms or how to reduce it.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Do yuo have some component that get update very often? Or a ngFor very big that get update?

Comment: Hello Jacopo thanks for your response.Well no.There isn't any component that is getting updated too frequently.The recording is on a page where i use a kendo grid with pagination and a maximum of 1000 rows.I cant really see the cause of the slow down and also cant see the meaning of that event handler.

Comment: Mh, the only thing that is in my mind now is to use the ` changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` strategy on the component that rended this kindo grid.

Comment: Moz has [another article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/09/generational-garbage-collection-in-firefox/) that covers the difference betweenMinor and Major GC.